# How i can get data from two tables in on query?

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I want to get all data from two tables, and cast it into StringBuffer, but i have an issue with query. I don't know how i should call it properly.

That method will show user created by him training plans. There will be two kinds of this plan. For example, in FBW_TABLE_SET_A_CHEST user selected exercise named "squeezing the barbell", and in FBW_TABLE_SET_B_CHEST user has selected exercise named "squeezing the dumbbell".

Here is how tables are called

```
private static final String FBW_TABLE_NAME_SET_A = "FbwSetA";
private static final String FBW_TABLE_SET_A_CALF = "calfExerciseSetA";
private static final String FBW_TABLE_SET_A_LEGS = "legsExerciseSetA";
private static final String FBW_TABLE_SET_A_BACK = "backExerciseSetA";
private static final String FBW_TABLE_SET_A_SHOULDERS = "shouldersExerciseSetA";
private static final String FBW_TABLE_SET_A_BICEPS = "bicepsExerciseSetA";
private static final String FBW_TABLE_SET_A_TRICEPS = "tricepsExerciseSetA";
private static final String FBW_TABLE_SET_A_CHEST = "chestExerciseSetA";
private static final String FBW_TABLE_SET_A_ABS = "absExerciseSetA";
private static final String FBW_TABLE_SET_A_FOREARM = "forearmExerciseSetA";

private static final String FBW_TABLE_NAME_SET_B = "FbwSetB";
private static final String FBW_TABLE_SET_B_CALF = "calfExerciseSetB";
private static final String FBW_TABLE_SET_B_LEGS = "legsExerciseSetB";
private static final String FBW_TABLE_SET_B_BACK = "backExerciseSetB";
private static final String FBW_TABLE_SET_B_SHOULDERS = "shouldersExerciseSetB";
private static final String FBW_TABLE_SET_B_BICEPS = "bicepsExerciseSetB";
private static final String FBW_TABLE_SET_B_TRICEPS = "tricepsExerciseSetB";
private static final String FBW_TABLE_SET_B_CHEST = "chestExerciseSetB";
private static final String FBW_TABLE_SET_B_ABS = "absExerciseSetB";
private static final String FBW_TABLE_SET_B_FOREARM = "forearmExerciseSetB";
```

And here is how i "created" it by db.execSQL(..)

```
db.execSQL("create table " + FBW_TABLE_NAME_SET_A + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + FBW_TABLE_SET_A_CALF + " TEXT," + FBW_TABLE_SET_A_LEGS + " TEXT," + FBW_TABLE_SET_A_BACK + " TEXT," + FBW_TABLE_SET_A_SHOULDERS + " TEXT," + FBW_TABLE_SET_A_BICEPS + " TEXT," + FBW_TABLE_SET_A_TRICEPS + " TEXT," + FBW_TABLE_SET_A_CHEST + " TEXT," + FBW_TABLE_SET_A_ABS + " TEXT," + FBW_TABLE_SET_A_FOREARM + " TEXT)");
    db.execSQL("create table " + FBW_TABLE_NAME_SET_B + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + FBW_TABLE_SET_B_CALF + " TEXT," + FBW_TABLE_SET_B_LEGS + " TEXT," + FBW_TABLE_SET_B_BACK + " TEXT," + FBW_TABLE_SET_B_SHOULDERS + " TEXT," + FBW_TABLE_SET_B_BICEPS + " TEXT," + FBW_TABLE_SET_B_TRICEPS + " TEXT," + FBW_TABLE_SET_B_CHEST + " TEXT," + FBW_TABLE_SET_B_ABS + " TEXT," + FBW_TABLE_SET_B_FOREARM + " TEXT)");
```

In sum: that method should get all data from two tables, and cast in into StringBuffer and show user created by him training plans.

Comment: It is not good idea to keep same data in multiple tables. Just merge them, and add column that identifies the set. Then you can select rows using WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `UNION` compound operator.

SQL code is something like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2 from table1 UNION SELECT col1, col2 from table2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.execSQL("SELECT * FROM " + FBW_TABLE_NAME_SET_A + 
"UNION" +
"SELECT * FROM " + FBW_TABLE_NAME_SET_B);
```

This should give you all non-duplicate rows of both the tables.